# Is ITC faster than IPC of the same kind?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, multiprocessing

I am trying to find out if there is an inherent speed difference between inter-thread and inter-process communication.

I know that when using threads the threads share the same memory, can use the same global variables, and the such while processes have to use other tricks, which basically means queues.

But take the following case:

An application is comprised of several completely separate `.exe` files. When all are run they form a producer/consumer (or publisher/subscriber) architecture, with some processes producing some values and other processes reading and using those values and maybe producing some other values.

This communication is done with conventional ways of IPC.

My question is: if I were to move the code around so that it's one process with multiple threads (assuming no conflicts with variable names and the such), but keep the communication methods the same, queues with all the locks and semaphores behind them, will the thread-based application be faster than the process-based one?

The startup costs of processes vs. threads are not important because the application is meant to run for a long time (hours) so a few milliseconds will not be important.

Google has yielded no conclusive answers to this.

To clarify some aspects of the question:

1. The factor I want to maximize is throughput.

   Some external factor (an arduino sensor for example) produces an input for one of the nodes and the entire network takes some time while all the nodes consume and produce values. Then a new input can be processed. I would like to be able to process more inputs per minute/second.
2. The data being passed back and forth are mostly numbers or small arrays of numbers.
3. The entire network can have lets say between 5 and 25 nodes.
4. As for platform (if it is relevant) I would like answers for both Linux and Windows.
5. The specific use-case is too large to be described here so consider the use-case provided above. This is as much, if not more, an educational question for my own knowledge as it is a question about a specific problem.

Please ask for any other relevant information that I have not included here.

Comment: You've already done this at least twice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67235353 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67237981, and have still not focused the questions. In fact, as far as I can tell, they're pretty much identical. Are you expecting a different reception to your question each time?

Comment: 1) "*if I were to move the code around ...*" is broad. There are *many* different ways of doing that, even within the constraints that you've enumerated later, and the answer is going to depend on all those conditions. "*The specific use-case is too large to be described here ...*" is problematic; we need to see the specific use case to know how to address the question. Otherwise we'd just be guessing at all the possible scenarios and how they affect the performance. Try to make a small demo of what you're referring to, and that may make the question focused enough.

Comment: 2) About reposting the same question: please don't do that. Instead, try to edit the original question by incorporating the feedback you get. If you repost the question, *especially* without linking to the previous versions, all context of what suggestions have already been made is lost, and you're basically expecting users to repeat the work already done by others, and that's not appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> If I were to move the code around so that it's one process with multiple threads (assuming no conflicts with variable names and the such), but keep the communication methods the same, queues with all the locks and semaphores behind them, will the thread-based application be faster than the process-based one?

That is not possible. The multiple thread version will take advantage of the shared memory space and the multi-process version cannot do so. For example, you can take an ordinary object in one thread and access it through a pointer in another thread, and all the referenced sub-objects will "just work". Anything not modified can be accessed just as easily in one thread as another with no special effort.

This simply won't work across processes at all since they don't share an address space.

Comment: The question is about moving from IPC to ITC. Threads have more possibilities than processes but when moving in the other direction you may be able to keep the same method of communication (ie. queues or pipes for example). My question is about the difference in performance when using the same methods of communication.

Comment: But they're not "the same method of communication". Queues between processes can't take advantage of shared address space. Queues between threads can. Pipes between threads can use shared address space and inter-thread locks. Pipes between processes can't.